# AngularJS TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object' Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am getting the above error on running Jasmine tests when mocking/spying an API call in my tests. Here is my code that calls the API:

```
UploadedReleasesController.$inject = ['$log', '$scope', '$filter', '$modal', 'ReleaseService', 'TrackService', 'APP_CONFIG', 'DeliveriesService'];
function UploadedReleasesController ($log, $scope, $filter, $modal, releaseService, trackService, APP_CONFIG, deliveriesService){
.
. 
.
releaseService.releases(vm.currentWorkspace).then(function (responseValues) {
            vm.albums = responseValues;
            if(vm.albums.length !== 0){
                vm.selected.album = vm.albums[0];
```

where `releaseService` is my defined service and `releases` is one of its method that I want to spy on. It takes a string argument let's say `'HIGH'`. Here is my test file where I want to mock that call:

```
describe('app module', function() {
    var vm, scope, modalInstance, releaseService, trackService, deliveriesService;

    beforeEach(module('app.uploadedReleases'));     // Main module name

    beforeEach(module('app.config'));       
    beforeEach(module('auth'));             

    beforeEach(function() {
        var mockReleasesData = {
            "test" : 100
            }
        };

        releaseService = jasmine.createSpyObj("releaseService", ["releases"]);
        releaseService.releases('HIGH').and.returnValue(mockReleasesData);
    });


    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $log, $rootScope, $filter, APP_CONFIG) {

        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        modalInstance = {
            close: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.close'),
            open: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.open'),
            dismiss: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.dismiss'),
            result: {
                then: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.result.then')
            }
        };

        vm = $controller('UploadedReleasesController', {'APP_CONFIG':APP_CONFIG, '$log':$log, '$scope':scope, '$filter':$filter, '$modal':modalInstance,
            'ReleaseService':releaseService, 'TrackService':trackService, 'DeliveriesService':deliveriesService});

    }));
```

Upon running the test, I get the error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'releaseService.releases('HIGH').and')
>           at test-release.controller.spec.js:93
>       TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'releaseService.releases(vm.currentWorkspace).then')
>       undefined

Here is the actual releaseService from `release.service.js`

```
releaseService.releases = getReleases;
 .
 .
 .
function getReleases(workspace){
        var releases = [];
        headers.Workspace = workspace;  // set the workspace
        var deferred = $q.defer();
       // Then make $http calls and return a promise
  .
  .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple things that may be issues:

1. Calling the `release` method:

`releaseService.releases('HIGH').and.returnValue(mockReleasesData);`

`releases` method is being called here, if a return value should be set here then I think the syntax may be:

`releaseService.releases.and.returnValue(mockReleasesData);`

Then you can assert on `releases` being called with the correct data.

2. After the above is resolved. The `mockReleaseData` doesn't have a `then` method.  Since it is being returend from `releases` its `then` method will be called:

`releaseService.releases(vm.currentWorkspace).then(function (responseValues)`

```
   var mockReleasesData = {
        "test" : 100
        },
        then: function(callbackFn) {  
          // could call callbackFn with fake responseValues
        }
    };
```

---

What is the intention of the test? Is it to exercise the `then` anonymous function?  With a small amount of restructuring to expose your logic it could be trivial to test.

```
function handleResponseValues(vm, responseValues) {
            vm.albums = responseValues;
            if(vm.albums.length !== 0){
                vm.selected.album = vm.albums[0];
}
```

This would still require that the `then` callback call `handleResponseValues` with a reference to `vm`, and `responseValues` but would expose all the logic independent of the promise chain.

Comment: That worked and my test runs for the case when I am just testing my controller. Could you explain more so I understand what is going on ? Especially with the `then: function(callbackFn)` and what is that supposed to be doing ? That will really help me understand, Sir